# Gson name array and include a new property

Tags: java, javascript, json, gson

I'm starting to work with json and need some help figuring this out.

I have a pojo

```
 public class HiReceiptsObj{
       private string warehouse_id;
       private String owner_id;
private String receipt;

.....// all with Getters and setters

}
```

I call a java method where I load an ArrayList of receipts like so

```
List<HiReceiptsObj> receipts = new ArrayList<HiReceiptsObj>();
```

and then I use gson to convert the ArrayList into json

```
String receiptsJson = new Gson().toJson(receipts);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(receiptsJson);
```

This will output

```
    [{"warehouse_id":"US01","owner_id":"NP   ","receipt":"INV"},
{"warehouse_id":"US01","owner_id":"NP   ","receipt":"082212-3047 "},
{"warehouse_id":"US01","owner_id":"NP   ","receipt":"INVADJUST"}]
```

I need this kind of output

```
{
  "total_pages": 10,
  "rows": [
   {"warehouse_id":"US01","owner_id":"NP   ","receipt":"INV"},
   {"warehouse_id":"US01","owner_id":"NP   ","receipt":"082212-3047 "}, 
    {"warehouse_id":"US01","owner_id":"NP   ","receipt":"INVADJUST"}
    ]

}
```

I have read other posts regarding this, but they are too advanced for me, can anybody please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should also have a holder class for your purpose:

```
public class ReceiptHolder {
    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    private int totalPages;

    private List<HiReceiptsObj> rows;

    // TODO: add getter / setters
}
```

2) Create `receiptHolder` instance and fill it:

```
List<HiReceiptsObj> receipts = new ArrayList<HiReceiptsObj>();
ReceiptHolder receiptHolder = new ReceiptHolder();
receiptHolder.setRows(receipts);
receiptHolder.setTotalPages(receipts.size());
```

3) Serialize `receiptHolder`:

```
String receiptsJson = new Gson().toJson(receiptHolder );
```

**Output as you wanted:**

```
{
  "total_pages": 10,
  "rows": [
    {
      "warehouse_id": "US01",
      "owner_id": "NP   ",
      "receipt": "INV"
    },
    {
      "warehouse_id": "US01",
      "owner_id": "NP   ",
      "receipt": "082212-3047 "
    },
    {
      "warehouse_id": "US01",
      "owner_id": "NP   ",
      "receipt": "INVADJUST"
    }
  ]
}
```